# Download file with excel-builder.js

Tags: javascript, excel

I've been trying to use excel-builder.js library to generate and Excel file and download it automatically, just as done [here](http://excelbuilderjs.com/cookbook/addingDataToAWorksheet.html).
Now, I must stress out that I'm rather new to front end development, otherwise I might have figured it out already...
Anyway, what I can't seem to figure out is what is this "downloader" in the example? **download** is required and **downloader** is used like magic, but for me it doesn't work (since I don't really know what to require).
Has anyone tried it successfully? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorry for the bother. As I stated, I'm new to this.
I found the relevant code, and like in other places, it has to do with creating an invisible form and submitting it.